# How can the sonar-maven-plugin be configured to successfully analyze Java 21 projects?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

How can I mitigate the following findbugs error triggered by `mvn sonar:sonar` after upgrading from Java 17 to Java 21?

```bash
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.10.0.2594:sonar (default-cli) on project my-project: 
Can not execute Findbugs: java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.umd.cs.findbugs.NoClassesFoundToAnalyzeException:
```

In the Java 17 version, I am able to execute the [sonar-maven-plugin](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-maven/), but it fails after the upgrade. These are the relevant parts of my root pom file:

```xml
<project...>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>   <!-- updated from 17 -->
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.10.0.2594</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Maven and Java versions**

```bash
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.4 [...]
Java version: 21 [...]
```

**Expected result**

The `mvn sonar:sonar` command should execute successfully when executed by the build server.

**Actual result**

```bash
[INFO] --- sonar:3.10.0.2594:sonar (default-cli)
[...]
[INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor [findbugs]
[INFO] Loading findbugs plugin: [...]/target/sonar/findbugs/findsecbugs-plugin.jar
[INFO] Findbugs output report: [...]/target/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
The following errors occurred during analysis:
  Error scanning com/company/example/SomeClass for referenced classes
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.<init>(FBClassReader.java:35)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:48)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:75)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:806)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:249)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:235)
      At java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
      At java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
      At java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      At java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

and many similar examples like `Unable to get XClass for java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup`, `Unable to get XClass for reactor/core/publisher/Mono`, etc

Comment: Seems like they simply not supporting Java 21 yet, since new Oracle's idea from Java 9+ - braking changes in ABI e.g. Panama over old JNI as well com.sun.misk.Unafe is no longer etc. So all performance tricks works for the industry for al least two decades broken and nothing works as expected. In the same time VM finally solves issues related to all this know workarounds.

Comment: Well, the "reason" for it not working with Java 21 (yet) seems to be them using an ASM version that isn't compatible with Java 21.

Comment: @VictorGubin for `sun.*` there are existing alternatives.. and about performance (in particular tricks) ... use more recent JDK's they are much faster than older versions..also about "sun.*" has been mentioned already in 199X not to use, but check this page https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/about-sunmiscunsafe (an in particular go to the video https://youtu.be/4HG0YQVy8UM?si=y2WegkCQ2qXgwXGE&t=210 (at 3:30) about "sun.*" package!!!)

Comment: @khmarbaise Yep and 1 000 000 librarians created since 1995 and all project have this librarians as dependencies have to provide updates, just because since Java 9 each new version we have backward compatibility broken (yep even original documentation from all tutorials since 1995 have warning - DON'T USE `com.sun*` packages, anyway libs with JNI accelerators always use them). Now everyone who just wanting to update Java to newest version faced with `to expensive` issue, since faced dependencies must be replaced with something.

Comment: The update to newest versions is ongoing since JDK9+ which is since 2017 also announced a year before JDK9 etc. the projects have handled that so I don't see the problem. If you start at this moment with upgrading to JDK9+ I think it's bit late... 1000000 libs created which have relied on that? I have my doubts that because central repo has not that much libs in total. Furthermore if not updated for so long I would say you have other problems... And if each update of the JDK version breaks something in your app I think there is some rethinking neccessary... also ignore EA builds for testing...

Comment: So what I don't understand is you seemed to blaming the JDK for changing things in areas which should NOT being used (as mentioned before known for decades).. And also the EA builds etc are long before available for testing.. So I know so many libs which doing pretesting; Furthermore the real problem here was in that case was to use a more recent versions of the ASM library (9.6) (sonarqube side) which supports JDK21 without any issue.

Comment: @khmarbaise `Furthermore if not updated for so long I would say you have other problems..` Yep issue is - business don't whant to pay for this upgrade, they ready to pay for some new business related features, not for upgrade because of upgrade or refactor because of refactor. Result - companies technical leadership's making decision to switch to competing technology stack : .NET, Python. Node etc. As result Java is no longer a TOP 1 in TIOBE index since JDK9 and going down year by year.

Comment: Oh gosh ... ok switch to other things and things are getting worse. Refactoring is a foundation of a software development. If not allowed or not done that's the problem..Refactoring and upgrades (deps, tools, runtime, os'es) is an invest into the future if not done it's doomed to fail in the future.. that's independent of the language. Also those updates have been missed in the past and now you pay for that... that you can't update because it's costs even more than in the past... This is a vicious circle. Observed that for decades. always making the same mistakes.. Embrace the change!

Comment: and if you can't get management to explicitly spend resources on refactoring, it might be possible to establish a culture of doing refactoring/updates together with other changes (ensuring the code is cleaner than previously after every change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was facing was that our server was using an old version of the [Sonar FindBugs plugin](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/). Since the plugin is downloaded to the build environment from the SonarQube server by the `sonar-maven-plugin` before the analyses starts (as explained in this answer at the [Sonar Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/fail-to-execute-mvn-sonar-sonar-using-java-21/102986/4)), the fix was to upgrade the plugin installed on the server accordingly. In our case, we bumped the FindBugs plugin from version `4.0.4` to version `4.2.4` in addition to bumping the Checkstyle plugin from version `8.40` to `9.3`. Please see the [SonarQube plugin matrix](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/) to see which plugins are supported by the different SonarQube versions.